# Returning entries that satisfies a specific condition in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

[image]I have a `df` which contains a `score system` , `score` , `patient_id` and `date time`. I would like to return all the entries of patient who has a 2 units increase in the `score` in the last 72 hours. How do I achieve this goal?

Comment: Please add an example of your dataframe, and expected output

Comment: I have added the image of a snippet of how my dataframe looks like. In output , I would like to return the count of entries  who satisfy the condition of " increase of 2 units in score in the last 72 hours"